# Recovering from discarded changes on visual studio code(git)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have discarded changes that i made on a specific file for accident and need to see what those changes are, maybe recover them, i already searched a lot of SO questions and didn't get any result, is it possible to see or recover those discarded files?

thanks.

Comment: In what way did you discard them?

Comment: Did you commited them (easy to recover)? Or at least staged them (harder but recoverable)? If no, there is no chance. You could at least install a vscode extension that do some timed backup for the next time.

Answer (score 1):

When you interface `git` using `vscode` and `vscode` asks if you want to discard changes it will prompt you with
[image]

Source: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/240625/29264526-c8a1b354-80dd-11e7-82d7-76e7b0066998.png from [joaomoreno](https://github.com/joaomoreno).

If you then decide to discard your changes they are gone (as discussing in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32405)